# Micro-services Authorization and session maintenance - spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I have application that I want to divide into micro-services to increase overall performance on high load. Overall structure I plan to create like this:

```
Web -> Authorization Server -> Eureka + Zulu -> Spring boot Micro-services
```

Since my previous application was monolith I used Spring boot + Spring security and had no problem while logging things like @CreatedBy @LastModifiedBy - I laso use Aspects to log every action in app and track who made the changes. Now since I don't have session across microservicies I don't know what to do - I do need to log the action owners - log who is doing what.

Can someone tell me how can I maintain the logging possibilities in my new structure. Maybe there is some ready made patters or maybe I need to make some changes in my structure?

Answer (score 0):

How are you dealing with authorization? If the web component calls the authorization server with an authentication token, that token should be forwarded when calling microservices. Every microservice should be stateless (so, no session is ever stored), and that token should contain information about the user so each microservice can access it and authenticate requests.

If you could specify what you mean by Authorization Server, I'll be glad to explain in greater detail.

Comment: Right now I haven't build authorization server yet - that 's just the idea how I plan to make changes. if you can give an example of what you just mentioned - will be great

Comment: For example, a very simple authorization server: You call it with correct username and password parameters, and it returns an encrypted token which contains the user's details (for example, its name, roles and the token's expiration time).

Now that the client has that token, it can use it to call any microservice needed. The microservices can decrypt the token because they know the same private key used by the authorization server and can access the logged user's information.

Comment: You mean that I need to send token myself to all my requests yes? Maybe there is easier way - Spring Security Client - or something like that?